# Jquery Mobile: getting error with mobile.pageLoading()

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, loading

With **jquery.mobile-1.0rc1**; getting error while working in simple dialog-

error-message in Chrome-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'pageLoading'
```

& in FF-

```
$.mobile.pageLoading() is not a function
```

Here is the code snippet-

```
$(document).delegate('#importCCRLink', 'click', function() {
  $(this).simpledialog({
    'mode' : 'bool',
    'prompt' : 'Are you sure to import?',
    'useModal': true,
    'buttons' : {
      'OK': {
        click: function () {
         showTempLoading();
        },
    theme: "p"
      },
      'Cancel': {
        click: function () {
          //alert('Cancel');
        }
      }
    }
  })
})

function showTempLoading()
{
    $.mobile.pageLoading();
}
```

-any idea!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove `$.mobile.pageLoading()` call and replace it with `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` and `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()`.